# How to disable the saving of logs in Spring batch metadata tables?

Tags: spring-batch

Currently Spring batch job is running for every 20 seconds and there are 3 jobs run concurrently.  So in effect there is an abrupt increase of the size of the Spring batch metadata tables below.  So is there a way we can disable this?  If not then how we can clean up in this table from time to time?

BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE,
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION,
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS,
and BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet** can be used in a spring batch job that you can schedule to run periodically to purge the spring batch working tables.

See https://github.com/arey/spring-batch-toolkit